# change color of image pixel by pixel

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I an trying to change color of a png image so that transparent area still remain transparent and give rest of the image a color this is what i tried

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatefrompng('2.png');
$w = imagesx($im);
$h = imagesy($im);

$om = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);

for ($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
        $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im,  $rgb);

        $orgb = imagecolorallocate($om,$colors['alpha'],$colors['alpha'],$colors['alpha']);
        imagesetpixel($om,$x,$y,$orgb);
    }
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($om);

imagedestroy($om);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

It produce image like: 
**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

i am still not getting an exact idea how can i get highlighted area of png image and give them a color such as yellow or pink without loosing transparency so that only non-transparent area will get remain transparent

Comment: You can simply use `imagecolorset` to change a specific color without touching the rest of the palette. Simply find the index of your green (for example) and replace it with yellow.

Comment: this is just an example image and i have no idea what image user provide so no idea that what color is in the image

Comment: this is also possible that multiple colors are used in the user proided  image

Comment: And you want to replace all colors by your specified color in that case? So basically creating a mask?

Comment: yes i want to all colors replace with my color without loosing transparency

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to work with the palette instead of going through every pixel in that case:

```
<?PHP
    $myRed = 255;
    $myGreen = 0;
    $myBlue = 0;

    $im = imagecreatefrompng('http://s25.postimg.org/ll0dzblan/image.png');
    imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($im, true);

    if (imageistruecolor($im))
    {
        $sx = imagesx($im);
        $sy = imagesy($im);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $sx; $x++)
        {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $sy; $y++)
            {
                $c = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
                $a = $c & 0xFF000000;
                $newColor = $a | $myRed << 16 | $myGreen << 8 | $myBlue;
                imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $newColor );
            }
        }
    } else {
        $numColors = imagecolorstotal($im);
        $transparent = imagecolortransparent($im);

        for ($i=0; $i < $numColors; $i++)
        {
            if ($i != $transparent)
                imagecolorset($im, $i, $myRed, $myGreen, $myBlue, $myAlpha);

        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Edit: Fixed if-condition inside the loop.

Comment: i tried your code but it still does nothing. will you please share your output image with change color by using this code

Comment: I edited the answer, this should hopefully work with truecolor images now.

Comment: thanks this is great and it work for me but please can you explain or modified your code that why it is not working on all png images such as this [link](http://s25.postimg.org/72g7umb2n/image.png)

Comment: [link](http://s25.postimg.org/j5q4vxbin/shadowcopy_php.png) this is produced by your code

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an image expert. What I notice with your last image ([link](http://s25.postimg.org/72g7umb2n/image.png)) though: My chrome itself doesn't seem to render it the way it should be. If I open the image in a tab I only see the left part of the torus. However if I drag it the outer right part becomes visible in the dragging-preview as well. Maybe something's sketchy with the image? Do you have another example by chance?

Comment: ccKep what you have done is a lot for me. i tried your code on these images [link](http://s25.postimg.org/ll0dzblan/image.png) , [link](http://s25.postimg.org/4aekl1j0v/image.png), [link](http://s25.postimg.org/wjbnhi9vz/image.png), [link](http://s25.postimg.org/vz17sk61b/image.png)  unfortunately some of them work great but some are not

Comment: please suggest me something how can i create shadow for all types of png images that have transparency

Comment: I've edited the code once more. This time the truecolor portion keeps the alpha value at every pixel and simply replaces the RGB values. These are two examples: [Image 1](http://i.imgur.com/oXCQ3Pl.png) and [Image 2](http://i.imgur.com/fXCX7pj.png). This increases the loading time though and you might want to implement a caching function (eg. save created images in a folder under a certain name (maybe the MD5 of the original image + .png) and look if they exist before any processing)

Comment: thanks a lot.this code create exactly what i want.you make my day.thanks you very much