# Why ImageColorSet() is not working in PHP?

Tags: php, rgb

I want to change RGB of (x,y)=(0,0) coordinate of a photo which I've uploaded from input tag. And I am able to get RGB of certain pixel but I am not able to change that pixel's RGB.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($image);

$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0); //(0,0)=(x,y)

imagecolorset($im,$rgb,255,255,255); //here i tried to change RGB

$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0); //After changing again I tried to get that pixel's RGB but new RGB is not showing 

$colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb); //I am indexing that RGB
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change color of image pixel by pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543051/change-color-of-image-pixel-by-pixel)